# Simulator mode hangs at Registering the application to run from layout

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, simulator

I can't get my UWP projects (even a simple hello world project) to run in simulator mode using VS2017. All projects hang at "Registering the application to run from layout..."

Things that I have done:  Repair VS2017 install, run SFC on my system, Login in to windows using Name and password", ensured Developer Mode is enabled, renewed developers license.

Note: projects run fine in Local Machine mode.  Also, simulator mode worked fine in VS2015.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a couple of days of net browsing,  I found someone who solved the problem by upgrading from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro.  Something to do with the simimulator requiring RDP functionality which the Home release does not support.

I just so happened to have a Pro license on an old PC, installed it and problem solved.

I don't recall where Windows Pro is a requirement for using VS2017.